# Call function after navigateUp or dismissing DialogFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, dialog, fragment-lifecycle

Hi I'm using function `loadExercises()` in my app for setting data to recyclerview. For every part of my app it's working fine. But in one specific part I need two specific things:

1. Refresh view after `DialogFragment dismiss()` method. (I'm updating exercise time in that dialog. This method is working fine and does what it should do.)
2. Refresh this list after `navigateUp()` called in `AddExerciseToTrainingFragment`. This fragment is another recyclerview full of exercises. On click it shows DialogFragment, which adds exercise to training a sets specific time. Again this method works, but I'm unable to "refresh" the list after navigating up.

The data is stored in the Firebase Cloud Firestore.

**Function for loading exercises (I'm calling this one in `onStart()` and `onResume()`):**

```
fun loadExercises() {
    trainingsViewModel.loadExercisesInTraining().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { result ->
        binding.result = result
        if (result is Result.Success) {
            adapter.submitList(result.data)
        }
    })
}
```

**Function loadExercisesInTraining from ViewModel:**

```
private val coroutineContext = viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO

fun loadTrainings(): LiveData<Result<List<Training>>> = liveData(coroutineContext) {
    emit(Result.Loading)

val result = trainingsRepository.getTrainings()

if (result is Result.Success) {
    emit(result)
}
```

}

Recycler view adapter:

```
class ExerciseInTrainingAdapter(
    private val onClick: ((ExerciseInTraining) -> Unit)? = null,
    private val fragment: TrainingDetailFragmentExercises
) : DataBoundListAdapter<ExerciseInTraining, ExerciseInTrainingItemBinding>(
    diffCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ExerciseInTraining>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(
            oldItem: ExerciseInTraining,
            newItem: ExerciseInTraining
        ): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(
            oldItem: ExerciseInTraining,
            newItem: ExerciseInTraining
        ): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
) {
    private lateinit var viewModel: TrainingsViewModel
    private lateinit var exerciseViewModel: ExercisesViewModel

    fun setViewModel(viewModel: TrainingsViewModel) {
        this.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    fun setViewModel(viewModel: ExercisesViewModel) {
        this.exerciseViewModel = viewModel
    }

    override fun createBinding(parent: ViewGroup): ExerciseInTrainingItemBinding {
        return DataBindingUtil.inflate<ExerciseInTrainingItemBinding>(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            R.layout.exercise_in_training_item,
            parent, false
        ).apply {
            this.buttonDelete.setOnClickListener {
                this.exercise?.let { deleteExercise(this.root, it.id.toString()) }
            }
            this.root.setOnClickListener {
                this.exercise?.let { goToExerciseDetail(this.root, it) }
            }
            this.exerciseTime.setOnClickListener {
                this.exercise?.let { setExerciseTime(this.root, it) }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun bind(binding: ExerciseInTrainingItemBinding, item: ExerciseInTraining) {
        binding.exercise = item
    }

//methods implementation
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. You can refresh your view in onDestroy() method of your DialogFragment.
2. To "refresh" the list, use notifyDataSetChanged() method of your recyclers adapter.

Comment: Hi, thanks I solved the 1. problem, but I have no idea, where should I call the notifyDataSetChanged() method.

Comment: "Refresh this list after navigateUp() called in AddExerciseToTrainingFragment" - after navigateUp :) Can you describe the problem?